# Is it possible to not apply a feat passive such as Rapid metamagic?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, actions, metamagic

The description of *Rapid Metamagic* (Complete Mage, p. 46):

> **[General]**
>
> You possess an uncanny mastery of your magic, enabling you to modify spells on the fly much faster than others can.
>
> **Benefit**
>
> When you apply a metamagic feat to a spontaneously cast spell, the spell takes only its normal casting time.

I'll have Arcane Spellsurge up, if my metamagic is all rapid, I won't be able to cast a regular spell + a metamagic one in the same round since the casting time will not be a standard action (from a full round action with the metamagic, so it'll be considered swift from standard) I could however cast a standard spell (from a full round spell + metamagic or not) + 1 standard spell with metamagic or not (to make it swift).

My DM will probably allow it as a house rule but I'd prefer an official rule if there is one.

I know about metamagic specialist + the incantrix class feature that let you do the same thing than rapid metamagic a few times per day.

Comment: Hi Maxime and welcome on rpg.stackexchange.com :) I've taken the liberty to simplify your question, please do review it to make sure I didn't forget anything valuable. A couple of tips: no need to mention the game / edition in the question, that's what tags are for; avoid citing whole rules, focus on the important bits, to avoid copyright issues; avoid "meta" statements such "sorry I am French", etc.., we'll work together to get your question in shape, no worries.

Comment: ok yes, I have a lot to learn, thanks. But I believe the bit that talks about the fact that you trained yourself to rapidly do metamagic is important, because in theory you could still cast slower metamagic, since you learned how to do it faster, for house rules at least.

Comment: ''You possess an uncanny mastery of your magic, enabling you to modify spells on the fly much faster than others can.''

Comment: *ok yes, I have a lot to learn, thanks.* So, do I, so do I. This is why I asked if you were comfortable with my edit! This is still your question, so it's your call in the end (as long as you follow the rules, obviously...). I'll put this tidbit back!

Comment: By the way, there's a sentence "edited just now" or "edited x hour ago" just above my username. It's actually a link, and if you click on it you can find the whole edit history of the question, and who performed which edit. You should even have a button to "revert" to a previous version if you think the edits are detrimental and prefer an earlier version.

Comment: I'll add it here: I know some passives cannot be ignored like for example if a feat would give natural armor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### No standard rule allows you to forgo the benefit of a feat.

The D&D 3.5 FAQ suggests that effects are mandatory unless stated to be optional. The example given is for a spell description rather than a feat, but DMG p.6, under *Adjudicating*, asserts that ambiguous situations should be interpreted by looking to existing rules which cover similar situations. On page 91 of the FAQ:

> The *teleport* spell states that you "can" bring along objects, which indicates that it isn't mandatory.

This is consistent with other mechanics. For example, there's no rule which allows a creature to voluntarily forgo their own damage reduction.

There *are* specific rules which allow a creature to voluntarily forgo a saving throw or resistance to magic (PHB p.177), voluntarily to lower spell resistance as an action (also PHB p.177), and voluntarily forgo Dexterity to AC when being caught while falling (PHB p.69). However, these rules imply that the *default* is you can't forgo an ability.

Now, *arcane spellsurge* (Dragon Magic p. 64) speeds up any spells with a standard, full-round or 2-10 turn casting time, and the spell description is very clear that you can't choose to ignore this effect. The feat Rapid Metamagic (Complete Mage p.46) makes a spell take only the normal casting time as if no metamagic was applied.

**However**, the FAQ also implies that you can apply the benefit of feats and other bonuses in whichever order is most beneficial (e.g. the Practiced Spellcaster questions on FAQ p.43), and there's no rule as to whether spells or feats apply first. You could, arguably, cast one Metamagic spell by applying the speedup from *arcane spellsurge* first, turning a now full-round spell into a standard, whereupon Rapid Metamagic would not reduce it any further.

Comment: ''enabling you to modify'' I think I'll focus on that part, for that feat, you can't forgo some feats but with this part I'll interpret it this way for our games, My DM will agree.

Comment: I accept your last paragraph answer, it indeed could be possible like that! thank you, and it's from official rules! Some feats/abilities really cannot be ignored though, like you said DR, or as I said natural armor, but this one yes in that situation, anyway the feat is always good when not used with arcane spellsurge, and now that I have an official solution during arcane spellsurge, it's always good!